# How can I verify how many hierarchical steps there are?

Tags: sql

| Company Name | Parent_ID | Company_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | NULL | 1 |
| ABC Subsidiary | 1 | 2 |
| ABC Subsidiary 2 | 1 | 3 |
| ABC Subsidiary 3 | 1 | 4 |
| ABC Subsidiary 4 | 1 | 5 |
| DEF | NULL | 6 |
| DEF Subsidiary | 6 | 7 |
| DEF Subsidiary 2 | 6 | 8 |
| DEF Subsidiary 3 | 6 | 9 |
| GHI | NULL | 10 |
| GHI Subsidiary | 10 | 11 |

If you look at the table, you will notice the following:

1. Parent companies have a Parent_ID = NULL
2. Subsidiary companies have a Parent_ID = Company_ID of the Parent company

Example: Company ABC has a Parent_ID of NULL meaning it is a Parent Company. ABC Subsidiary companies all have a Parent_ID = 1, which is the Company_ID of ABC.

How can I verify that there are only two steps in the hierarchical structure? I want to be certain that there are not any Subsidiary companies that roll up to a company with a valid Parent_ID? In other words, how can I be certain that there are no subsidiary companies that roll up to another subsidiary company?

I tried:

```sql
select *
from table1
where Parent_ID is null
```

I assumed this would show me all of the companies that are Parents but it does not verify how many steps there are.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I've also removed the conflicting tags. When you [edit] your question to replace the image, also (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: If you are wanting to ensure that you only two levels perhaps this is not the right design? The design you have allows any number of levels. This is well suited for things like an organization chart or other types of things where it can be several layers deep. It sounds like you want only a parent/child to be allowed. Maybe just using two tables would be better here?

Comment: This is a good usecase for a recursive CTE. Can you share what RDBMS you are using (sql server, mysql, postgres, oracle, etc) as the syntax is slightly different with a few of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following sql request :

```
SELECT T1.* FROM table1 as T1, table1 as T2
WHERE T1.Parent_ID is not null 
AND T2.Company_ID = T1.Parent_ID
AND T2.Parent_ID is not null
```

This will display all the subsidiary companies that roll up to another subsidiary company.